# Non-existent table referenced in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

If I have a table that is mapped in `persistence.xml` and has an `@Entity` class, will JPA/Hibernate require the physical table to exist even if I don't ever try to access it?

Comment: No it won't, but why don't you just try it out?

Comment: If you mapped an ```@Entity``` in the persistence.xml that means you will be able to acces that entity and that table. That is the main purpose of JPA. You can enable entities' auto-detection and manage entity inclusion / exclusion manually. If you set <exclude-unsilted-classes> to true you must add entities directly. Any other entities will be excluded.